# Not consistent Libre Calc text paste AND cell reference/formulas

Tags: libreoffice, paste

This is really awkward.

I tried pasting from a text file twice with different results.

The first time the number 1/4 (which is 0.25 OZ) became the date 2017-04-01 while 1 became number 1.

But the second time, the number 1/4 became 1/4 while 1 became the date 1899-01-01!

How can the same text be interpreted differently? Why does LibreOffice not treat all text in the pasted columns the same but tries to guess badly instead?

Comment: if the field/column/row/area has been defined as a date; whatever you post will be interpreted as a date; likewise number, percentage, ....  hence you have a paste, paste-value, paste-formatting (this is from memory; hence wording may differ).  all spreadsheets do the same; if you're not used to spreadsheet formatting you may not have noticed the formatting rules.  (prior contents can influence format, if you've not defined that area's format)  ... (blame visicalc; from there is copied to lotus123, multiplan, excel... thru to sheets & calc)

Comment: if the cell is not defined as a value, then it tries to interpret it as text. ie a date

Comment: as I recall (i no longer use spreadsheets often) there is a key that causes the interpretation to be forced; eg. entering 'blah will force it to be text/blah or "blah"; likewise numbers, dates, % & other format types

Comment: @guiverc -- yes there is. I also forget, but I think = will force a value. Also, spreed sheets work mainly in decimal, not sure how well fractions are supported

Comment: I fixed the issue by replacing 1/4 in the original text file with 0,25 and so forth. Another issue occured though.